# ¿Qué significa "español galopado" en este contexto?

Tags: traducción, expresiones, significado

De *El Cuaderno de Maya:*

> «¡Jué! ¡Qué niñona tan bonita esta gringuita! ¡Que Juesú me la guarde!
>   El caballero la estaba esperando, del mismo modo que todos en la isla,
>   y ojalá le guste el pollito con papitas que le preparé.»
>
> No era un dialecto de la zona, como pensé, sino **español galopado**.

Si yo fuera a atreverme con una conjetura, diría que quiere decir truncado, o sea las últimas sílabas no son pronunciadas o son elididas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obteniendo [un poco más de contexto](https://books.google.com/books?id=AkUDE4wgbgUC&lpg=PT26&ots=DT5nAtlrDC&dq=No%20era%20un%20dialecto%20de%20la%20zona%2C%20como%20pens%C3%A9%2C%20sino%20espa%C3%B1ol%20galopado.&hl=es&pg=PT26#v=onepage&q=No%20era%20un%20dialecto%20de%20la%20zona,%20como%20pens%C3%A9,%20sino%20espa%C3%B1ol%20galopado.&f=false):

> Llegó con una olla de hierro, pesada como un cañón, que se puso a calentar en la cocina, mientras me **dirigía un discurso precipitado**, algo así como se presentaba con el debido respeto [...]
>
> [ - Aquí el texto original de la pregunta - ]
>
> [...] No era un dialecto de la zona, como pensé, sino español galopado. **Deduje** que Manuel Arias era el caballero [...]

En ese contexto vemos que la interlocutora se expresa con un **discurso rápido, precipitado**, tanto que al narrador o narradora le cuesta seguirlo, de ahí que al final exprese "pude **deducir** que...". Es decir no era fácil de entender. Costaba entender las palabras y al principio pensó que no era español, sino algún otro tipo de dialecto.

Galopar, en este contexto tiene el sentido literal del "[ir al galope](http://dle.rae.es/?id=InAydO8)", que es lo que hacen los caballos cuando van más rápido (creo que los caballos pueden ir al *paso*, al *trote* y al *galope* y cada uno es más rápido que el anterior).

Por eso nuestro narrador viene a decir "Esa señora hablaba tan rápido que me costaba entenderla. Al principio pensé que era porque hablaba algún tipo de dialecto de la zona que yo no entiendo, pero luego me di cuenta de que sí que estaba hablando español, pero muy rápido (al galope), de manera muy atropellada".

Un "español *galopado*" es simplemente un español hablado muy rápido.

Comment: Ah, la intérprete de Audible, quizá lo leyendo por primera vez, lo ha leído con una voz cajún en lugar de apresurado que me ha despistado, pero es mucho mejor que escachando los voces sintético. Por ejemplo la gracia hubiera sido perdido por diseño si una máquina hubiera procurado decir "chinito-­come-aloz"